# Delete associated record instead of settings fk to null with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following associations:

```js
Training.hasMany(Exercise, {
  foreignKey: 'trainingId',
  as: 'exercises',
});

Exercise.belongsTo(Training, {
  foreignKey: 'trainingId',
  as: 'training',
});
```

Considering I have the records `exercise1` and `exercise2` associated with the record `training`. When I do `training.setExercises([exercise2])`, I expect the `exercise1` to be deleted and the `exercise2` to be kept, but instead, sequelize do an update on `exercise1` to set the `trainingId` to null. Isn't it supposed to delete the record? If this is the expected behavior, how do I make it delete the record instead of updating the FK to null?

Comment: Also, when sequelize does that, an error is raised in the database because the `traningId` is an FK with `NOT NULL` set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. As per [the docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/has-many.js%7EHasMany.html#instance-method-set):

> Set the associated models by passing an array of persisted instances or their primary keys. Everything that is not in the passed array will be **un-associated**

Note that everything else will be un-associated, not deleted. To my knowledge non of the association functions will ever delete a resource unless you have cascades configured on the tables.

There isn't a single query that will achieve what you want but something like this should suffice. It's recommended you perform the following in a transaction if your database supports it.

```
// get existing associated exercises
const exercises = await training.getExercises();

// associate the new exercise
await training.addExercise(exercise2);

// delete the previously associated exercises
for (let i = 0, n = exercises.length; i < n; i++)
{
    await exercises[i].destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the one from @ankh, but there are other alternative solutions. The reason I still want to use `set<recourse_name>s` method is that it takes care of keeping the existent records, it won't just replace everything. I came to two solutions but first, it needs the FK in the entity been managed to have `allowNull: false`. This way, when using the `set<recourse_name>s` method, it will unset as expected (setting the FK to null) and won't raise an exception. After this, you have two alternatives:

The first is to call `<managed_entity_model>.destroy({ where: { <fk_name>: null }})`. Doing this, you will delete all the records that were unset.

Code accordingly to the example from the question:

```js
// This will set the FK in the un-associated records to null
training.setExercises([exercise2]);

// This will delete the records that have the Fk set to null
Exercise.destroy({
  where: { trainingId: null },
});
```

The second is to set up a trigger to delete records on the update of the FK to null in the managed entity. So when the method there updates the FK to null, the database will take care of removing the record. The advantage over the first solution is that this one makes only one query to the database and the update doesn't happen since it's canceled after the delete. An example of this trigger below:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_<managed_entity_table>_on_update_of_<fk_name>_to_null()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
  IF NEW."<fk_name>" IS NULL THEN -- If the FK is set to null:
    DELETE FROM <managed_entity_table> WHERE id = OLD.id; -- Delete the record
    RETURN NULL; -- And cancel the update since the record is deleted already
  ELSE
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER delete_on_update_of_<fk_name>_to_null
BEFORE UPDATE OF "<fk_name>"
ON <managed_entity_table>
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_<managed_entity_table>_on_update_of_<fk_name>_to_null();
```

Code accordingly to the example from the question:

```js
// The database will take care of deleting the un-associated records in
// the same query
training.setExercises([exercise2]);
```

The result of any of these solutions is that the unset records won't exist. But take care since the FK is set as `notNull: false`. If you don't mess with it directly, always using the sequelize methods for the relationship, there will be nothing to worry about.

Comment: Great writeup, I'm glad you found a solution!